# Negotiate 404 with SignalR 2.2.1 in Asp.net core application

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, signalr

I've been strugging with this one for a few days now...

I have an Asp.net core application which uses .Net 4.6 and SignalR 2.2.1. When running locally in IIS Express from VS 2015 on a Windows 10 pc, everything works fine. It even works when deploying to IIS 10 on my local machine.

However, when deploying to IIS on a vm running Windows Server (I've tried 2008 R2, 2012 R2 and 2016 TP5), I consistently get a 404 error when SignalR tries to negotiate. Running as the default website, http://localhost/signalr/negotiate returns a 404. /signalr/hubs still returns the correct js as far as I can tell.

The weird thing is, I tried setting it up on an old vm running Windows Server 2012 R2 and for some reason it works fine, which makes me think it is a setup issue, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is.

Any suggestions would be appreciated as I really am grasping at straws now...

Answer (score 2):

enable load user profile in application poll on IIS

Comment: In my situation, one version of IIS had defaulted this to true so it was working but on another version, it was false.  Once I changed it true it worked.