# signalR + IIS 404 negotiate angular4 client (1.0.0-preview1-final)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 with Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR (1.0.0-preview1-final).

I have an issue deploying my application using IIS (with Kestrel). 
When I run the server in localhost using IIS Express, everything works as expected, but when I try to run on IIS (Windows server or local host windows 7), the negotiate call fail to *404*

> POST http://localhost/notification/negotiate 404 (Not Found)

[image: 404 response content]

I tried configuring IIS with different topics found online, but no success.  (`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`, extension-less url with https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/980368/a-update-is-available-that-enables-certain-iis-7-0-or-iis-7-5-handlers)

But I am still pretty sure the issue is related to my IIS configuration since the entire project works fine on IIS Express...

This is the `web.config` file used on the test server
(I removed the different debug tries, since it was not working...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyProject.Web.App.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: {{some GUID here}}-->
```

Part of the code used in `Configure` method

```
        app.UseSignalR(route =>
        {
            route.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notification");
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
```

Part of the code used in `ConfigureServices` method

```
        services.AddMvc()
        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddSession();
```

Angular application code

```
constructor() {
    /** ... **/

    this.hubConnection = new HubConnection('/notification', {
        transport: TransportType.LongPolling
    });

    this.hubConnection.on('Update', (data: string) => {
        let res = new DefaultNotificationInfo(data);
        /** ... **/
    });

    this.hubConnection.start()
        .then(() => {
            this.join().then(next => {
                // nothing to do on join, the socket is running
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error)
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
        });
}

private join(): Promise<any> {
    return this.hubConnection.invoke('Join');
}
```

---

**Versions informations :**

IIS :  **7.5**

APP net package.json:

```
        {
        /** ... **/
        "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.0-preview1-update1",
        "@aspnet/signalr-client": "^1.0.0-alpha2-final",
        /** ... **/
        }
```

API asp net nuget version : **(1.0.0-preview1-final)**

---

After reading 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/ and 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-0-preview1-getting-started-with-signalr/, I am pretty sure I've covered everything from their tutorial/quick-start

Is there something I missed?

---

### Update 1

After finding this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014264/3198096
I tried to enable the LoadUserProfile property of my ApplicationPool using this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity/

But this is still failing to 404.

I also tried to "Attach to process" on my application to see if there was any logs corresponding to my `Hub` or to the `/negotiate` url, but there was none.

*(also added a screenshot of the 404 result)*

### Update 2

This is an extract of package.config from the Web.App

[image: package.config file extract]

### Update 3

This is the configuration of the server hosting the applications.
You can see 3 different website. All of them have almost the same configuration. (Just the port changing, which define 3 different test environment access)

[image: IIS server Config]

And this is the basic localhost developer IIS, which I guess i generated by Visual Studio.

[image: IIS local Config]

Comment: Can you post the code for your Hub?  Do you have Authentication in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very similar issue on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1647). If the website isn't hosted on the root (ex. by using virtual directories or something similar), SignalR will use the wrong URL at the moment of writing. For example, if your "website-root" is on

```
http://YOUR_URL/test/index.html
```

you would have to use

```
this.hubConnection = new HubConnection('/test/notification', {
    transport: TransportType.LongPolling,
    logger: signalR.LogLevel.Trace
});
```

If the above doesn't work, I suggest you to add logging to your client app (as shown above) and your server. This will show you what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: The issue were not link to virtual folder but the github issue offered me my answer. I was not using the correct BaseUrl, and therefore the handshake call would point to the wrong URL on IIS (since it is not hosted on root)...

(Can you update you're answer to indicate the correction so I can grant you the bounty and accept the answer?)

Comment: @Humbertda I tried to update the explanation. Glad I could point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `app.UseSPA()` in your middlewares pipeline? if so try adding it after `app.UseSignalR()` like this

```
 app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<TestHub>("/hubs/test");
    });

app.UseSpa((o) =>
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            o.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
        }
    });
```

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/1511

Comment: I do not have UseSpa middleware on the project, I added a picture of the nuget dependencies, maybe I need to upgrade some package to get it?

Comment: @Kahbazi Damn! I've been searching through the internet like crazy since the last couple of days to fix this. I went through cors and all but this solved my problem buddy... Thanks much! You saved my day!!